# How to do a calculation on levelling?

Tags: civil-engineering

I got a question on levelling. But I don't know how to do that. My question is in the picture below, with the values

The questions are in the picture. Can you guys please help me to do this question? I get same value for one position of the equipment in one side. But in the other side the height is different. I don't understand why is that.

I need to find the error of the equipment and the height difference between x & y. I uploaded my progress on comments. And here is my rough work. [image: my rough work is in the picture]

Comment: I get 3.46 for both x & y in position A. But i get 3.92 for y in position B and 3.96 for z in position B. But it can't be. Is it an error of the equipment.

Comment: I did that question. Finally I got the error of equipment as 0.46.  but I don't know whether it is correct or not

Answer (score 1):

- The first thing to note is that we are not provided with the level of the stations at A and B. We should therefore not assume that they are at the same height.
- We know (from question (a)) that there is an error in the measurement in units of mm/m. Therefore we can assume that all levels are wrong, *but that they are wrong by a consistent error*, and the size of the error is proportional to the distance from the instrument. Let us call this error **e** mm/m
- Therefore, working from A: the true height of Y from instrument A is 3.46 + 24e. The true height of Z from A is 3.46 + 42e. Hence the difference in height between Y and Z is 18e.
- Working from B: the true height of Y from B is 3.92 + 36e. The true height of Z from B is 3.96 + 18e. Hence the difference in height between Y and Z is 0.04 - 18e.
- Therefore 18e = 0.04 - 18e, e = 0.04m in 36m = 1/900 m/m = 1000/900 mm/m ~ 1.111 mm/m

---

*The methodology shown above can be extended to give the actual height differences between X and Y and between Y and Z. As this is a homework question, I suggest the OP attempts this themselves, and comes back with any problems they have.*

Comment: I got the height difference between x and y as 0.323 and height difference between y and z as 0.02. is it incorrect?

Comment: That agrees with what I get.